# -[CFString hash]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, eventkit, cfstring, ekevent

I'm trying to fetch `EKEvent`s from the Event Store to populate a `UITableView` and display a month list view.

Basically it works and I'm doing it like this:

```
- (void) reloadEvents
{
    for ( NSString *entry in self.calendarA )
    {
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

        [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:[appDelegate.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:[appDelegate.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate fromString:entry] endDate:[[NSDate fromString:entry] midnight] calendars:nil]]];    
        [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:[self initializeItems:[NSDate fromString:entry] withEndDate:[[NSDate fromString:entry] midnight]]];        
        [tempArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES] autorelease]]];

        [[self.calendarD objectForKey:entry] addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                   {
                       [self redrawTableCells];
                   });
}
```

`reloadEvents` is called from within a

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
{
    [self reloadEvents];
});
```

as fetching events happens synchronously and it locks the UI for that time, I'm using GCD. The `NSDate` parts are my own categories on `NSDate`.

Now, when my view controller loads, events are fetched from the Event Store and displayed correctly. The view controller also listens for `EKEventStoreChangedNotification` and that's where my app crashes. When I change an event outside my app it receives a notification and tries to reload the event data, but then...

> `*** -[CFString length]:` message sent to deallocated instance 0x666f530

**EDIT**
I've changed `reloadEvents` to the following:

```
- (void) reloadEvents
{
    NSArray *daysArray = [[self.calendarD allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    for ( NSString *entry in daysArray )
    {
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:[appDelegate.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:[appDelegate.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate fromString:entry] endDate:[[NSDate fromString:entry] midnight] calendars:nil]]];    
        [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:[self initializeItems:[NSDate fromString:entry] withEndDate:[[NSDate fromString:entry] midnight]]];        
        [tempArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES] autorelease]]];

        [[self.calendarD objectForKey:entry] addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
        [tempArray release];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                   {
                       [self redrawTableCells];
                   });
}
```

and with this, the app doesn't crash anymore.
Seems like something changed `calendarA` and therefore the entry was already deallocated (which, after having found the cause of the problem, is absolutely logical).

Comment: I don't see any issues with code you've posted. I see you have set environment variable NSZombieEnabled to YES, check this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940198/exc-bad-access-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-but-im-using-arc/7940254#7940254, look for chown user's answer and try debugging . If possible can you create a small project with this code (that crashes) and post it here.

Comment: Is it possible that something running in another thread is changing calendarA?  That would mess up the enumeration.

Comment: There's not enough code here to diagnose.

Comment: I guess @Flyingdiver was right. Something did change my array in the meantime, which messed up the enumeration. After changing the code a bit, it now works as expected. Thanks you very much!!!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write that comment up as an answer and then accept it.