# LLDB equivalent to GDB's "info malloc-history <address>" command?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I am trying to resolve a "message sent to deallocated instance " error in iOS.

Comment: Use instruments, it gives you that info.

Comment: @Richard, Using the Zombie instrument will help you debug that, but sometimes it is nice to know the history of the malloc while sitting in gdb.

Comment: That would be fine if Instruments didn't lock up the machine

Answer (score 44):

See the LLDB-GDB command map (http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) - you have to import a script, and the command is named malloc_info now. Obviously, malloc stack logging still needs to be turned on in the scheme options.

```
(lldb) script import lldb.macosx.heap
(lldb) malloc_info --stack-history 0x10010d680
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't show dealloc's - didn't GDBs malloc-history show that as well?

Comment: when I looked at the linked page, it showed those commands as "available on Mac OS X only"

Comment: For me, the first line had to be 'command script import lldb.macosx.heap', otherwise the console would report 'error: 'malloc_info' is not a valid command.' (Mac OS)

Comment: `(lldb) script import lldb.macosx.heap`
*>>> "crashlog" and "save_crashlog"   command installed, use the "--help" option for detailed help
"malloc_info", "ptr_refs", "cstr_refs", "find_variable", and "objc_refs" commands have been installed, use the "--help" options on these commands for detailed help.*

Answer (score 2):

Use instruments, you'll get the exact line -

(In XCode) **Run it through "Product" -> "Profile".**

This will start Instruments, there you should **choose "Zombies"** and reproduce the bug event.

You'l get a pop-up once a zombie is called, **press the chevron to see the exact line**.

Problem is usually a bad `__bridge` (optional bridges `__brige_retained` / `__bridge_transfer` / `__bridge`)

Comment: I'm not quite seeing the exact line. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: @lwdthe1 You can see in Xcode output the deallocated Class that the message was sent to - it would give you a hint regarding the deallocated instance.

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to use the malloc_history command-line tool from a shell and give it the process ID and address of interest.  It appears this command is no longer installed by the latest Xcode's command line tools. :-(

Comment: malloc_history is installed and working for me, with xcode 4.6.3.