# Getting info about bad memory address in LLDB

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, lldb

I am trying to debug an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my iPhone app.  It is crashing on a method call and on the line of the method is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = xxx)`.

Before, I would have just used `gdb info malloc-history <xxx>` to start debugging, but I am having trouble finding a parallel command in `LLDB`.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738994/lldb-equivalent-to-gdbs-info-malloc-history-address-command) thread that said to use Instruments, but when I do I still get the crash but I can't figure out how to tell exactly where the app is crashing from in Instruments.

I just need to figure out where this piece of memory that is crashing was pointing to.  What is the best way to do this either using `LLDB` or Instruments?

Comment: Have you tried to turn NSZombie on? That helps in many EXC_BAD_ACCESS cases!

Comment: So you're getting crash on device or simulator? NSZombie works only on simulator.

Comment: I did not realize that. That explains why I never saw any difference when working with NSZombie. Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This problem is very easy to solve with an informative backtrace. Unfortunately with the latest version of iOS and Xcode, a good stack track is sometimes hard to come by. Fortunately you can set an 'Exception Breakpoint' in Xcode to allow you to examine this code prior to the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

1. Open the breakpoint navigation in Xcode 4 (This looks like a rectangle with a point on the right side)
2. Press the '+' button at the bottom left and add an 'Exception Breakpoint'. Ensure you break 'On Throw' for 'All' exceptions.

Now you should get a full backtrace immediately prior to this exception occurring. This should allow you to at least zero in on where this exception is being thrown.

Comment: Both of your answers were really helpful, but this is how I ended up figuring out where my problem was. Now I just have to fix it :). Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 44):

You can see the malloc stack if you debug using instruments.

I encountered the same problem as you and similarly wanted to know how to get the malloc history when using lldb.  Sadly I didn't find a nifty command like `malloc-history` found in gdb.  To be honest I just switched my debugger over, but I found that annoying since I felt I shouldn't have to do that.

### To find the malloc history using instruments:

1. Profile your project
2. Select Zombies from the list of instruments
   [image]
3. Make your app trigger the problem
4. At this point you should be presented with the address that was already deallocated and you can explore it.
   [image]
   It should be a simple matter of viewing the malloc history at this point.  I blacked out portions that had class / project names specific to the work I'm doing, but I think the essence and usefulness of how to go about getting this information is present.

### A Last Word

The problem I ran into yielded a message like:

> *** -[someClass retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x48081fb0 someProject(84051,0xacd902c0) malloc: recording malloc
>   stacks to disk using standard recorder

I was really puzzled where this `retain` was coming from since the code it was breaking on didn't have one (not in the getter or setter of the line it was on).  It turns out that I was not calling `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` when a certain object was `dealloc`'ed.  Later in execution KVO occurred do to a setter on a line and that blew up the program since KVO was trying to notify an object that was already released.

Comment: is there a way to debug stray kvo notifications ?

Answer (score 15):

you can use command like this in lldb:

```
image lookup --address 0xec509b
```

you can find more commands at:[LLDB TO GDB COMMAND MAP](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have zombie issues, in fact I was just digging through the data encapsulated by a `CGImageRef`. This was the trick!

Comment: @tristan its not printing anything :(

Answer (score 10):

Maybe is too late but for further assistance, on LLDB:

```
(lldb) p *(MyClassToPrint*)memory_address
```

E.g.

```
(lldb) p *(HomeViewController*)0x0a2bf700
```