# libc++abi.dylib: handler threw exception -- but no stack trace in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, gcc, llvm

I am using XCode 4.5 with LLVM. In older versions of XCode, when there was a crash it would give me meaningful debugging information. Lately I keep getting crashes that simply say "libc++abi.dylib: handler threw exception," and don't provide a stack trace that shows where the exception came from. This is totally useless to me. What are the proper debugging settings that I should set up so that I can find the location of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a breakpoint and set it to break on all exceptions

Comment: How does one do this exactly? Is this a universal breakpoint?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @robin you might be right in this case. kinda.. I grant you my 'answer' is too broad :) sorry

Comment: @Jason Yes, there is an "universal" breakpoint (In Xcode 4, in breakpoint navigator, press + button). Check this SO answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9891258/1606534