# lldb debuge (lldb) shell malloc_history 1545 0x2ffcc000

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

i am use xcode 4.6:i want to use lldb to debug:

IFC_findComments:foreignId:offset:source:noCache:] [第5669行]:IFC_findCommentsXXXX
2013-02-21 18:26:06.478 myshine[1545:707] -[AppDelegate applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:] [第467行]:applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning

myshine(1545,0x2ffcc000) malloc: *** error for object 0x8e4a14: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

```
(lldb)  malloc_history 1545 0x2ffcc000
(lldb) shell malloc_history 1545 0x2ffcc000
```

(lldb)

but if i input shell malloc_history 1545 0x2ffcc000  not see anything

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738994/lldb-equivalent-to-gdbs-info-malloc-history-address-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither malloc_history not shell are valid LLDB commands.
I am surprised LLDB does not at least complain about that.